# Conditional xml serialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have the following C# classes :

```
public class Books
{

public List<Book> BookList;

}

public class Book
{

public string Title;
public string Description;
public string Author;
public string Publisher;

}
```

How can I serialize this class into the following XML?

```
<Books>
  <Book Title="t1" Description="d1"/>
  <Book Description="d2" Author="a2"/>
  <Book Title="t3" Author="a3" Publisher="p3"/>
</Books>
```

I want the XML to have only those attributes whose values are not null/empty.
For example: In the first Book element, author is blank, so it should not be present in the serialized XML.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should be able to use the `ShouldSerialize*` pattern:

```
public class Book
{
    [XmlAttribute] 
    public string Title {get;set;}

    public bool ShouldSerializeTitle() {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Title);
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Description {get;set;}

    public bool ShouldSerializeDescription() {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Description );
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Author {get;set;}

    public bool ShouldSerializeAuthor() {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Author);
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Publisher {get;set;}

    public bool ShouldSerializePublisher() {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Publisher);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was unclear on how the above solution worked until I read the following post:  http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2006/02/conditional-xml-serialization_08.html

Comment: +1 Coolest thing I never knew about :) Just solved a particularly sticky backward-compatibility problem with this gem.

Comment: Note that ShouldSerialize method **should** be public here, unlike other cases like PropertyGrid serialization control where the method can be private and yet not be ignored.

Answer (score 8):

Alternative :

- Switch your public fields to properties
- Define default values with the `DefaultValueAttribute` attribute
- Define content property with the `ContentPropertyAttribute` attribute
- Use XamlWriter/XamlReader

You end up with something like this:

```
 [ContentProperty("Books")]
 public class Library {

   private readonly List<Book> m_books = new List<Book>();

   public List<Book> Books { get { return m_books; } }

 }

 public class Book
 {

    [DefaultValue(string.Empty)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(string.Empty)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(string.Empty)]
    public string Author { get; set; }

 }
```

Comment: This should be the answer. ShouldSerialize* works, but [DefaultValue("")] is by far simpler method

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Books
{
    [XmlElement("Book")]
    public List<Book> BookList;
}

public class Book
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Title;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Description;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Author;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Publisher;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var books = new Books
        {
            BookList = new List<Book>(new[] 
            {
                new Book 
                {
                    Title = "t1",
                    Description = "d1"
                },
                new Book 
                {
                    Author = "a2",
                    Description = "d2"
                },
                new Book 
                {
                    Author = "a3",
                    Title = "t3",
                    Publisher = "p3"
                },
            })
        };

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(books.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, books);
    }
}
```

And if you want to remove the namespace from the root node:

```
var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, books, namespaces);
```

Also I would recommend you using [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) instead of [fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) in your model classes for better encapsulation:

```
public class Books
{
    [XmlElement("Book")]
    public List<Book> BookList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is this actually answering the question about skipping the null/blank items?

Comment: Indeed my code works for null elements, but it doesn't work for blank elements (they will still be present in the generated XML).

Comment: I believe, when u use properties, by default, the value is null and hence the attributes wont be present in the generated xml unless they r set to empty or any other value.

Comment: Fields are also `null` by default for reference types and the default value for value types.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use "Specified"-property like (works like "ShouldSerialize()"):

```
public bool <<Your XML-property name here>>Specified
{
    get { return <<your condition here (i.e. not null check)>>; }
}
```