# How do I Selectively Serialize Fields and Properties using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, serialization

The problem is I have a test class and a TestVariable and I would like to Serialize the Test Class without Serializing the TestVariable.:

```
public class TestClass
{

    public int TestVariable
    {
        get;
        set;

    }
    public int ControlVariable
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public TestClass()
    {
        TestVariable = 1000;
        ControlVariable = 9999;
    }
}
```

The Code that does the serialization:

```
public static void PrintClass()
{
    new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestClass)).Serialize(Console.Out, new TestClass());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the Namespace System.Xml.Serialization and adding the attribute [XmlIgnore] over the field or property that you want to be excluded in Serialization.

Modifying the Above code it would look like this:

```
public class TestClass
{

    [XmlIgnore]
    public int TestVariable
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int ControlVariable
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public TestClass()
    {
        TestVariable = 1000;
        ControlVariable = 9999;
    }
}
```

This will cause TestVariable to be completely excluded from the serialization.

Comment: I find this approach inflexible, because it's defined during compile time. IMHO, [Conditional XML serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094985/conditional-xml-serialization) using [`ShouldSerialize*`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/53b8022e(v=vs.110).aspx) methods is much more flexible.

Comment: I would have to agree that its certainly inflexible but sometimes you may not need the level of flexibility that ShouldSerialize Methods give you.

In my case, I had a class where I knew at compile time that I would never need to serialize those values. So I've chosen a simple solution that gets that job done.

I couldn't find a very simple solution upon searching so I posted my problem and findings so that others could benefit from it.